# Integrate Salesforce CRM into an external app

Tags: salesforce1-app

I'm a complete newbie in the Salesforce universe, so I beg forgiveness if what I'm asking sounds dull.

I'm currently working on a Django app that serves a mobile app (the front-end mostly) that also has a web version. Some of the functionalities icnclude a lot of typical CRM functionality: resource management, agenda, staff management, scheduling, etc. Thus, instead of going for specific Django available CRM out there, I'm considering using Salesforce CRM....if that's even possible I mean. I know some people has do something similar in the past (Hotel Ninjas), although I couldn't find any info on that topic

That said, the Salesforce is just too big for me to grasp this....I know there is the CRM itself, but also this Salesforce Platform1....which one should I be using if I wanted to integrate some of the CRM functionalities in my Django app?

Maybe what I'm saying makes no sense at all....please share your toughts!

Comment: Salesforce1 is just an interface for mobile use. It all uses the Salesforce ecosystem. You cannot have Salesforce1 without salesforce.

Comment: Thanks @Eric, I'm concerned about how hard it is to integrate Saleforce in an existing app, and whether is worth it or not. Still discovering, there is a LOT to look at, but it seems feasible, at least, plus you get a lot of features that seem really interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Salesforce provides all standard ways to connect external system:

- SOAP
- REST

On Salesforce end you can build Webservice and use those webservice from the Django App by generating WSDL

OR

you can build some APIs on Django App and expose them to be leveraged by Salesforce code.

In brief, Salesforce is a fully functional CRM which can connect to your external system (your app can also connect to it) if your app has a single scope of integration like using SOAP, REST, WSDL, SSO etc. CRM support OAuth 2.0 and all widely used technique. So, you can make a solid bridge between your application and Salesforce CRM.

Comment: Hello @Ashwani, thanks for the response. But does that mean that I would need to rebuild my Django model so it uses what I think is call Objects in Salesforce? Or can I still use my model and have the information duplicated? I'm asking because I already have a Django model with some of the typical entities used in a CRM: Clients, Events, etc...

Comment: No, you will not need to rebuild. You will need to build some APIs by whuch Salesforce system can interact. @AlejendroVK

Comment: OKie, great, can you point me on any specific docs for this? The vast amount of info in Salesforce is overwhelming, I'm currently looking at the Getting Starter Guide for SF Platform 1 (https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/starting_force_com/starting_intro#challenge) ...is this the right place to look at? Thanks!

Comment: @AlejandroVK you find the best place. Trailhead is the best way to learn Salesforce.